# jQuery page autoloading scrolling script - in need of explanation

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, autoload

I'm having trouble undesrtanding how the script exacly works, and what can i do to improve it, minify etc. I'd also like to find a way for appending button, that would stop the function (sort of disable autoloading of content button), do you have any idea? Here's the code: (the most important part for me is to understand the code)

```
var page = 1;
var pageLast = 1;
var stop = false;
function lastPostFunc() 
{ 

    $('div#loading').html('loading data ...') ;
    page += 1;
    if (page+1 > pageLast) {
        stop=true;
    }
    var objURL = new Object();
    window.location.search.replace(
        new RegExp( "([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g" ),
        function( $0, $1, $2, $3 ){
        objURL[ $1 ] = $3;
        }
        );
    q = '?strona='+page
    for (var k in objURL){
        if (k != 'strona' ) 
            q += ('&'+k+'='+objURL[ k ])
    }
    data = $('<div/>').load( "/shop/category/example/" + q +' #produkt_lista',function() {
        $('.produkt .opis',$(this)).each( function() { $(this).css('display', 'none'); } );
        $('a.jt').cluetip({ cluetipClass: 'jtip', arrows: true, dropShadow: false, hoverIntent: false, sticky: false, mouseOutClose: true, showTitle: false, closeText: 'zamknij', width: 300, positionBy: 'mouse', topOffset: 0});
    });
    if (data != "") {
        $('.paginator').hide();       
        $("#produkt_lista").append(data);            
    } 
    $('div#loading').empty();
}; 

$(document).ready(function() { 

pageLast = parseInt( $('.paginator .paginate-pages').first().text().replace('Stron: ',''));
$('#produkt_lista').after( $('<div id="wczytywanie" style="display: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; line-height: 40px; color: red; margin: 20px auto; width: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>') );
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop()+200 > $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           if (!stop) lastPostFunc();
        }
});
} );
```

Comment: You just asked like 4 questions.

Comment: Well the main question is about understanding the code (i understand it partialy only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script basically binds that `lastPostFunc()` function to the `$(window).scroll()` event. It says if the user scrolls down to the bottom 200px of the screen, JavaScript should fire that function.

All the function does is show a loading div, likely a modal or overlay, and then fetches the next page of data:

- /shop/category/example/?strona=1#produkt_lista
- /shop/category/example/?strona=2#produkt_lista
- /shop/category/example/?strona=3#produkt_lista

..and so on. It then iterates over all the nodes which match the CSS class `.produkt .opis` and hides them using `$(this).css('display','none');`. It should just be using `$(this).hide();`, but it'll work either way.

After that it binds a `cluetip` plugin to all the anchors with the class `.jt` and passes in some various plugin parameters. I imagine that is so you can hover those with your mouse and some fancy tooltip will appear near your cursor.

Finally it checks if data is not empty and hides the paginator element (dont know why) and appends the newly fetched HTML-wrapped data to the existing data inside `#produkt_lista`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, i've got the core concept and you explained it even better to me, i have most problems understanding everything between var objURL and the q loop. Btw is there simple way to make event, that stops the function from working?

Comment: If you want to stop the function from working just set `var stop = true` at the top.